# HTML audio preload

Tags: html, audio, preload

I have a sound effect that I need to play whenever someone taps on something but the first tap sound always lags and then it's fine after that. I understand it should have something to do with the preload but I've had preload set to auto the entire time.

```
<audio id="effect" src="audio/bloop.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

How can I get rid of that initial lag?

Comment: Are you using Safari on iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incase you are using - **Safari on iOS**:
Preloading  and  on iOS devices is disabled to save bandwidth.

In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.

Source: [Safari Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1)

Comment: I am using iOS in this case. Is there a work around for this? Would I be able to play the sound with the volume set to 0 when they start a level so it preloads?